# Pointer arithmetic with differing types and understanding the results?

Tags: c#, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Consider the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int max = 1024;
    var lst = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i *= 2) { lst.Add(i); }

    var arr = lst.ToArray();

    IterateInt(arr);
    Console.WriteLine();
    IterateShort(arr);
    Console.WriteLine();
    IterateLong(arr);
}

static void IterateInt(int[] arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Iterating as INT ({0})", sizeof(int));
    Console.WriteLine();

    unsafe
    {
        fixed (int* src = arr)
        {
            var ptr = (int*)src;
            var len = arr.Length;
            while (len > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(*ptr);
                ptr++;
                len--;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void IterateShort(int[] arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Iterating as SHORT ({0})", sizeof(short));
    Console.WriteLine();

    unsafe
    {
        fixed (int* src = arr)
        {
            var ptr = (short*)src;
            var len = arr.Length;
            while (len > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(*ptr);
                ptr++;
                len--;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void IterateLong(int[] arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Iterating as LONG ({0})", sizeof(long));
    Console.WriteLine();

    unsafe
    {
        fixed (int* src = arr)
        {
            var ptr = (long*)src;
            var len = arr.Length;
            while (len > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(*ptr);
                ptr++;
                len--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, by no means do I have a full understanding in this arena. Nor did I have any real expectations. I'm experimenting and trying to learn. However, based off what I've read thus far, I don't understand the results I got for `short` and `long`.

It is my understanding that the original `int[]`, when read 1 location at a time (i.e. `arr + i`), reads `4` bytes at a time because of the *data types* size and thus the value `*ptr` is of course the integral value.

However, with `short` I don't quite understand why every even iteration is `0` (or arguably odd iteration depending on your root reference). I mean I can see the pattern. Every time I iterate 4 bytes I get the real integral value in memory (just like iterating the `int*`), but why `0` on every other result?

Then the `long` iterations is even further outside my understanding; I don't even know what to say or assume there.

## Results

```
Iterating as INT (4)

1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024

Iterating as SHORT (2)

1
0
2
0
4
0
8
0
16
0
32

Iterating as LONG (8)

8589934593
34359738372
137438953488
549755813952
2199023255808
-9223372036854774784
96276819136
32088581144313929
30962698417340513
32370038935650407
23644233055928352
```

What is actually happening with the `short` and `long` iterations?

Comment: The shorts that are zero are the upper two bytes of every int (which are zero because you made you them zero). The longs will make more sense when viewed in hexadecimal.

Comment: @harold, so the `short`'s are 0 because the numbers are so small. If I had started with a much higher value it may not be showing `0` is what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, for 65536 and higher.

Comment: Your `len` calculation is wrong.  It should be something like this:  `var len = arr.Length * sizeof(ACTUAL_TYPE) / sizeof(CAST_TYPE);` (`var len = arr.Length * sizeof(int) / sizeof(short);` -> `arr.Length * 2`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `pointer[index]` it gives you `sizeof(type)` bytes at location `pointer + index * sizeof(type)`. So by changing the type that you "iterate with" you change the stride.

- With `short` you read halves of the original `int`'s. Small ints have all zeros in their upper half.
- With `long` you read two `int`'s at the same time, forced into one `long`. At `ptr[0]` you are reading, for example, `(1L << 32 | 2L)` which is a big number.

You are still using the original `Length` measured in int-units, though, which is a bug. In the `long`-case you are reading outside the bounds of the array, in the `short` case you are reading too little.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So in the `long` case; am I reading another applications memory plausibly?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud thanks to virtual memory, you cannot accidentally read other apps memory. You read random memory of your own process. (Likely, it was from the same managed heap, all zero-initialized. But that's just coincidence).

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I don't understand this expression: `(2L << 32 | 3L)`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud when you read a `long` at `ptr[2]` it gives you the 3rd and 4th int in the original array mushed together. The 3rd int will be shifted by 32 bits. I think the constants in my expression are off but the idea stands. I tried to substitute correct numbers in my answer.

Comment: So when you say shifted by 32-bits, `1` becomes `10000000000000000000000000000000` in binary right?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud do I have to count the number of zeros now? :) Yes, correct. Except, that `1 << 32 == 1` while `1L << 32 == int.MaxValue+1`.